# Is this formula for Standard Error just for a sampling distribution that's normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, mean, standard-error

This basic formula of finding the Standard Error (Or Standard Deviation) of a Sampling Distribution,

S.E= s/sqrt(n)

Where

s= std deviation of sample

n=sample size

Is this only for the Sampling Distributions of "Means" alone and of those that are Normally Distributed?
Or does it apply to other point estimates, or other distributions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the standard deviation of the sample mean for any distribution, not just the normal. This follows from the theory of cumulants. Also, it is exact for any $n$, not just asymptotic.

It is not the standard deviation of any sample moment or other sample aggregate quantity, just of the mean.

Comment: It will be exact or asymptotic depending on the exact definition of s - it is not clear from the question whether S is based on the sample values (in which case it will be asymptotic) or is the population standard variation (in which case it is exact).